# C++, win32 error

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to run the code below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>
HDC GetPrinterDC (void)
{
    DWORD dwNeeded, dwReturned ;
    HDC hdc ;
    PRINTER_INFO_4 * pinfo4 ;


        EnumPrinters (PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 4, NULL,
            0, &dwNeeded, &dwReturned) ;
        pinfo4 = new PRINTER_INFO_4 [dwNeeded/sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_4)] ;
        EnumPrinters (PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 4, (PBYTE) pinfo4,
            dwNeeded, &dwNeeded, &dwReturned) ;
        hdc = CreateDC (NULL, pinfo4->pPrinterName, NULL, NULL) ;
        free (pinfo4) ;

    return hdc ;
}
```

but I keep getting the error "Win32Project1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.". When I press continue I endup with the error "Debug assertion failed".
The error is happening on the "free(pinfo4)" line.

Any help would be most appreciated.

**Additional Notes**: also tried "delete [] pinfo4;"

**Additional Notes**: The program displays this when it breaks. It is **not** my code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwFUfWkiqC7VZkdrU04zZ3pqZUU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try `delete [] pinfo4;` instead of `free`

Comment: nope, still getting the error

Comment: @behnam: did you actually rebuild the project? How does the error change?

Comment: what happens if dwNeeded is not divisible by sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_4)?  You would end up running past end of allocated memory...

Comment: @antipattern, where does it say in the documentation that dwNeeded needs to be divisible by sizeof(.)?  Have a look again: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  **The buffer must be large enough to receive the array of data structures and any strings or other data to which the structure members point**.  It is possible that it uses memory at the end for strings or other info.

Comment: Retracting my comment, did not read the docs properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, emphasis added:

> **”** the buffer must be large enough to receive the array of data structures *and any strings or other data* to which the structure members point. If the buffer is too small, the `pcbNeeded` parameter returns the required buffer size.

This means that buffer is not all array. Hence computing the number of array items and allocating only that can give you a too short buffer. Consider either just allocating bytes, or rounding *up* instead of *down* the division result.

---

Also, don't allocate with `new` and deallocate with `free`. That's formal UB. Instead, just use a `std::vector` of bytes.

Comment: ahh I think this was the solution. should have used this instead:pinfo4 = new PRINTER_INFO_4 [dwNeeded] ;

Comment: @behnam, no.  you should have used this: pinfo4 = (PRINTER_INFO4*)new unsigned char[dwNeeded];

Comment: Why does to small a buffer cause an error when I'm trying to free up the resources?

Comment: @behnam: A too small buffer can cause the called function to write beyond the buffer's end (because the original code told it that the buffer was larger than it was guaranteed to be). Writing beyond the end, a **buffer overrun**, can have all sorts of nasty effects. It's just general UB.

Answer (score 2):

Insted of `free (pinfo4) ;` you should use `delete[] pinfo4`. Use `free` together with `malloc` - and thats for C programs. In c++ use `new` and `delete.`

Another strange thing about your code, you use: `pinfo4->pPrinterName,`, but `pinfo4` is an array, so you should use rather: `pinfo4[0]->pPrinterName`, or some other index. Also make sure dwNeeded is non zero.

Comment: @behnam - you should look for sample code, ie.: http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=146&ver=vcpp, looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <winspool.h>
HDC GetPrinterDC (void)
{
    DWORD dwNeeded, dwReturned ;
    HDC hdc ;
    PRINTER_INFO_4 * pinfo4 ;


        EnumPrinters (PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 4, NULL,
            0, &dwNeeded, &dwReturned) ;
        if (dwNeeded <= 0)
            return NULL;
        pinfo4 = new PRINTER_INFO_4 [dwNeeded/sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_4)] ;
        EnumPrinters (PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL, NULL, 4, (PBYTE) pinfo4,
            dwNeeded, &dwNeeded, &dwReturned) ;

        hdc = CreateDC (NULL, pinfo4[0]->pPrinterName, NULL, NULL) ;
        delete [] pinfo4 ;

    return hdc ;
}
```

Comment: error C2819: type '_PRINTER_INFO_4W' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
and Error 2 error C2232: '->_PRINTER_INFO_4W::pPrinterName' : left operand has 'struct' type, use '.'

Answer (score 0):

You probably allocating less space than needed. Consider (theoretical) situation where dwNeeded = 5 and sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_4) = 4.

Your code will allocate single ( 5 / 4 == 1 ) PRINTER_INFO_4 and EnumPrinters will overrun supplied buffer. It is better to allocate exactly dwNeeded BYTEs and than reinterpret_cast them to PRINTER_INFO_4.

And, as marcinj said, you should use either malloc/free or new[]/delete[].